# Writing a Node SDK for API- How to upload a file along with other params in multipart format?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a node SDK and one of the endpoints allows for a file_upload parameter. I'm currently using the standard https library to make my calls, and I wonder if I should continue using it or move to something the "requests" library given that I need to do file uploads.

Here is an article I was reading through to build multi-part file upload functionality into the https module, but the article doesn't say the best way to combine the multi-part file form data and additional parameters say "test_mode=true" or something like that.

[how to upload a file from node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744990/how-to-upload-a-file-from-node-js)

Wondering if I should move over to requests complete or if this approach seems good then how can I add the above multi-part form functionality but extend it to allow for additional parameters in the body as well as a file binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module uses the [`form-data`](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data) module for [sending `multipart/form-data` requests](https://github.com/mikeal/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads). You could also use `form-data` by itself if you don't want to use `request`.